# Is there a way to use Kubernetes RBAC to stop a user from creating an external loadbalancer on a service?

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kops

On 1.10.9, kops, AWS, I am looking for a way to stop a user from creating a service that uses type:loadbalancer unless it has

```
annotations: 
  service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0.
```

Is that possible?

Comment: i think , you can define a custom role that has only get , list on the resource type service of type load balancer and Not create

Answer (score 2):

A custom role for users , with rules like this:

```
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["service"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"] .   ( dont put create ,update,patch etc)
```

This will prevent the users.

Then use [NodePort-Exposer](https://github.com/kubermatic/nodeport-exposer) to do the second part automatically without involving the users.

*The NodePort-Exposer watches Services with the annotation **`nodeport-exposer.k8s.io/expose="true"`** and exposes them via a Service of type LoadBalancer.*

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to prevent them to create a load balancer (and not any type of service), you can use a Resource Quota:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: object-quota-demo
spec:
  hard:
    services.loadbalancers: "3"
```

And then apply it a the namespace level:

```
kubectl apply -f quota.yaml --namespace=web
```

An attempt to create a load balancer when exceeding the quota will result in an error like the following one:

```
namespace/web unchanged
deployment.apps/web-server4 unchanged
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "webserver4.yaml": services "web-server-service4" is forbidden: exceeded quota: object-quota-demo, requested: services.loadbalancers=1, used: services.loadbalancers=3, limited: services.loadbalancers=3
```